# Precompile ASP.NET website into static files like HTML, CSS, javascript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, html

Is there a way to precompile a simple ASP.NET website (that does not use asp webform or any .net controls) into static files like HTML, CSS, javascripts?

I'm asking because I would like to leverage on the master page feature and some visual studio IDE intellisense while not giving up the flexibility of deploying my output to both Linux and Window server.

I found a manual solution here but would love to learn if there are other tools that help does this - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sd_patel/OutputASPtoHTML11242005063740AM/OutputASPtoHTML.aspx

Comment: Once you've introduced master pages you are using .net controls. The master page has code behind that handles paths when client pages are in different directories.

Comment: @JonP is there any workaround? I love master page but need to deploy my website on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to convert your ASP.Net site to static files, there are lots of "website downloader" utilities that will take a URL and download all of the resources for a site locally.  The one I have used is [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/).

You would run your website from Visual Studio, copy the url from the browser, and then give that url to HTTrack to download.  (Note that HTTrack will make some changes to the downloaded HTML so that it can be saved locally.)

Answer (score 0):

You can (allegedly) run .net on Linux. [See Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) or more specifically, http://www.mono-project.com/Start. It is not exactly what you are looking for but may achieve the same goal.